# How can you tell if a file is a text file without using the file utility?

Tags: bash

I'm in the middle of a bash script which at some point needs to distinguish between two categories of files: text files vs. non-text files (images, core dumps, binaries).

Normally, to find out if mystery file `foo` is a text file without relying on the file name extension, I'd call `file foo` and see if `text` is somewhere in the output.

What can I do if the OS doesn't have the `file` utility? Edit: Alas, I do not have permission to install anything on the OS.

I'd prefer a fast, local, and portable solution if possible (which will work on any Linux machine vs. sending the file to another computer and asking it to run `file`).

Comment: UNIX systems don't *have* "file type" metadata unless their filesystems contain significant extensions from POSIX (there have been folks who've thought to store this content in xattrs, but it never caught on). `file` does a bunch of heuristics, with a database (the "magic" database) containing signatures for different filetypes used to compare headers against. You could implement these heuristics, or a subset of them, yourself if you really needed to, but there doesn't exist a simple answer simply because there isn't a simple "file type" flag or field that can be read.

Comment: Do you want to just read the first N bytes, and see if they contain only printable characters? That's easy enough.

Comment: What Charles is saying is correct, but I know `file` is pretty cool. I would suggest to simply install it if it isn't present already (it should, in 99% of cases) . Coding *something like `file`* in bash would make no sense IMHO. Also you need to know that a program should never rely on the output of `file`, the program can just provide a good guess since UNIX system have no filetypes.

Comment: Do you have Perl? Perl's `-T` and `-B` operators attempt to guess whether a file is text or binary. (But if you don't have either Perl or `file`, the `file` command may be a lot easier to install.)

Comment: What is this mystery OS?

Comment: Alas, no perl either. Mystery OS is small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `file` should be your first choice.  If that is not possible, here a simple attempt at testing whether a file is text or not.  The following reads the first 1000 characters of file and tests for the presence of non-printable characters:

```
head -c1000 file | sed 's/[[:print:][:blank:]]//g' | grep -q . && echo "Not Text"
```

Or:

```
head -c1000 file | tr -d '[:print:][:blank:]' | grep -q . && echo "Not Text"
```

#### Character Encoding Issues

For the above to work, `sed` (in the first command above) or `tr` (in the second) needs to understand the file's character encoding. The encoding that [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) expects depends on the current locale and it supports many encodings including UTF-8.  As mklement0 notes in the comments however, GNU `tr` does not support UTF-8.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29), this is true of most versions of `tr`:

> Most versions of tr, including GNU tr and classic Unix tr, operate on
>   single-byte characters and are not Unicode compliant. An exception is
>   the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heirloom_Project) implementation, which provides basic Unicode
>   support.

Comment: Of course, this might fall down when given something like a UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded file, or even ISO-8859-*... But it's probably about the best that can be done in such a limited environment...

Comment: Nicely done, but you should also match `\t` (tab characters). With `tr` you could use `[:print:]\t`, but POSIX `sed` doesn't recognize escape sequence `\t`, so using `[[:print:][:blank:]]` is simplest.
Quibble: `tr`'s operands are _implicitly_ character classes (sets), so there's no need for the enclosing `[…]`: in fact, using them means that you'll _also_ match _literals_ `[` and `]` (which _happens_ to do no harm in this case); ergo: use `[:print:]` rather than `[[:print:]]`.

Comment: @twalberg: Good point in general, but it should work as long as the file's encoding matches the current locale's (thus, UTF-8 will typically be fine). Curious exception: _GNU_ `tr` (as of coreutils 8.21) is NOT locale-aware; by contrast, GNU `sed` _is_. Try `tr -d '[:print:]'  <<<oö`, which _should_ return an empty line, but prints `ö` (_BSD_ `tr` works fine). Contrast this with `sed -n 's/[[:print:]]//gp' <<<$'oö'`, which works fine.

Comment: @mklement0 and twalberg good points, thanks.  I have updated the answer with character encoding information.